# SQLite QueryAsync does not execute

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a method that returns an ObservableCollection of MapPins. When I run the following code, it returns all pins (working), but I need to return just pins that belong to a user.

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<MapPinModel>> GetPins(string userId)
    {                
            var pins = await _database.Table<MapPinModel>().ToListAsync();

            ObservableCollection<MapPinModel> retPins = new ObservableCollection<MapPinModel>(pins);

            return retPins;
    }
```

Therefore, I have used this code to return all Map Pins for a user -

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<MapPinModel>> GetPins(string userId)
    {
            var pins = await _database.QueryAsync<MapPinModel>("SELECT Id, UserId, Name, Latitude, Longitude FROM MapPinModel WHERE UserId = '", userId + "'");
            
            ObservableCollection<MapPinModel> retPins = new ObservableCollection<MapPinModel>(pins);

            return retPins;
    }
```

However when the second code is used, it returns nothing. When I put a breakpoint on the var pins line, the breakpoint breakpoint hits, but it doesnt move to the ObservableCOllection conversion, it just stops and the app continues to load.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var pins = await _database.Table<MapPinModel>().Where(p => p.UserID == userId).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: apologies I didnt mention in the post, I have tried that and it produces the same result as the QueryAsync.

Comment: are you positive that there are rows in your data that match?

Comment: I will say yes, BUT I have removed the WHERE from the SQL and I get data back, so I guess its not populated in the data somewhere and you are right. I will keep looking! Thanks

Comment: you can't just look at the UserID field in the returned data to check?

Comment: The breakpoint doesn't get hit, its weird like VS has a bug. It wont simply let me see what data is returned.

Comment: Looking at my add code, the UserId field is null at the point of adding to the database. That looks to be the problem!